# Visual Studio Community for Mac - Change browser from Safari to Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

In VS on windows I have the option to change which browser I debug with. On my Mac I'm not getting an option to change the browser.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac will use the default browser. So a workaround would be to make Chrome the default browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, I guess options like this will be added over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your default browser to Chrome: It'll change in visual studio too.
go to: 
apple icon on the top right -> system preferences -> General -> Default Web Browser: select Google Chrome (Drop down menu).

Comment: My Mac browser is set to Google Chrome for Mac (not Parallels) and it is still trying to use Parallels Windows Chrome.

Comment: one does not necessarily want to change the default browser for the system. this should be titled as a work around

Answer (score 0):

i've multiplets projects in my solution, when i changed the startup projects to more than one app , it allowed me to change the default debug app to what i want , changed the web app to edge and api app to the terminal

works like charm without changing the default web browser for the sysytem